# JAR executes in terminal but not display in browser

Tags: java, php, jar, centos, exec

**EDIT 1**

Could it be that by the time the jar executes in the background, the browser has finished executing the php file and hence it does not display the output of the jar?

Anyone please?

---

I am having some issues with executing a jar file from a php.

I do not have any problems when doing

> java -jar myjar.jar

**in my terminal**, as it executes fine.

But when I do

> echo exec('java -jar myjar.jar');

in php nothing appears.
When I put 2>&1, it returns me 0 or Array() depending if I use exec or system.

I also have one issue, but I do not know if it is related. When I try to do

> echo exec('java -version');

nothing is returned also. But in terminal it works fine again.

Anyone please?

Thank you!

Comment: The behavior of `exec` depends on the kind of PHP library and the kind of server software that uses this library. From what I know apache2 has some security checks in place that restrict the execution of external applications. What happens if you do `echo exec('java -version 2>&1');`?

Comment: You need to investigate any error codes and error messages.  It might be that java is not on the path or that your jar is not found.

Comment: @HaukeP.
Thank you for replying. 
I got something echoing now, which is:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04,mixed mode)`

Plus I also get an error when I echo the $output which is an
`Array to String conversion in path/to/my/php/file `

Does it show something that could help?
Thank you.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you! But if I run the same command in my terminal its fine. Can it be the case that the jar is not found when run in the exec?

Comment: @HaukeP. I tried it with passthru() and its fine now. When I do passthru('java -version') I get everything printed. But for my jar, I still do not know what to do. Nothing gets printed out.

Comment: Have you tried `passthru('java -jar myjar.jar 2>&1');`? Does that print any errors? And have you tried moving your jar file into the same directory as the php script temporarily? And which php version and which http server do you use?

Comment: @HaukeP.
Doing `passthru('java -jar myjar.har 2>&1');` returns a 0.
I did move my jar to the same directory, did not work. 

In fact I have tried to run the php script in my terminal from the /opt/lampp/bin/php and it worked fine. The jar was executed and it appeared. So I was wondering that maybe the problem in the end came from the browser. Could it be that by the time the jar executes, the browser has finished processing the php page and that might be why it does not appear on my browser. Could it be?:S

Comment: Could you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before calling the `passthru` command and check if it changes the behavior?

Comment: @HaukeP. No it does not change. I still get a 0 as return value.

Comment: Have you tried providing an absolute path? E.g. `java -jar /absolute/path/to/myjar.jar`?

Comment: @HaukeP. Yes I did. A 0 is still returned to my browser with the absolute path.

Comment: Okay, I'll be out of ideas soon. Does the http server log (or the php error log) contain any useful information?

Comment: @HaukeP. I found the php error log at /opt/lampp/log/php_error_log, but it is empty. :S

Comment: Since you seem to be using apache (deducting from the "lampp" in the path name you posted above), you should also check the apache log.

Comment: I cannot find the apache log. It is isnt anywhere. ><

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the PHP function you use.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php:

***Return Values**
The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.
Returns false on failure.*

*To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.*

I would not be able to make much sense of the return value of that function. In case of failure it is false - does that imply it is a boolean value, meant to be true in case no failure occurred? Maybe that explains why in the examples there is no use of the return value of exec.